# Maya does not sync with Fruux CalDav calendar

Tags: calendar

I'm trying to configure Maya to sync with a calendar on the Fruux.com service via the CalDAV protcol.

I tried launching the app via the terminal to look for error messages but do not see any.

I tried deleting and re-adding the calendar to no avail.

I was successfully able add both fruux  CalDAV accounts to Maya, however the events do not sync, and when I try to create a new event in Maya, the event will not save.

Still no error output in the terminal during all of this.

Here's a screenshot of the configuration with PII (personally identifying information) blanked out.

[image]

Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: Why are you launching from the terminal? I was able to add my Fruux calendars, but the events are all two hours early. This only happens on Elementary. My calendars sync correctly with my Ubuntu machine and my Android phone.

Comment: I'm launching from the terminal so that I can see any error messages that might be generated by the application.

Comment: I have the same issue, could you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. Was hoping that issue would be fixed by Loki release. If not I plan on posting a healthy bounty at bountysource to add explicit Fruux support to Maya calendar when I get some extra dough. Will update this post with that link when I do.

Comment: @StevenRoose I posted a [bug report-#1564461](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1564461) for this issue, please comment with any relevant debugging info

Comment: I have 3 Fruux calendars in my calendar, works without any trouble...
(Elementary OS Loki)

Comment: @Taxicletter Do you mind posting a screenshot of your account settings configuration so I can compare?

Comment: How did you got Fruux calendar to work with Calendar app? Did you use principal link found from instructions or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working after using the explicit calendar URL available under the 'other' clients setup option at https://fruux.com/sync/new/

Do not simply use 'https://dav.fruux.com/' as the calendar URL otherwise it will not work.

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar experience using Fastmail. Maya really needs to do a better job of telling you whether it can actually connect to the CalDAV server or not - I believe it just fails silently at the moment.